# callback functions for cakephp elements?

Tags: cakephp, element

This might be a naive question since I am new to cakephp.

I am working on a project where there are many layouts, helpers and elements. Because this is a mutli-language site, I am intercepting the final rendered output to do some language conversion(so each visitor only sees his native language on the site including user input).

I've managed to convert most of the layouts and helpers by adding code in two places: AppController's afterFilter() and AppHeler's afterRender() function. But I can't figure out a centralized way to handle the elements and there are dozens of them.

So here are my questions: do all elements in cakephp have a common ancestor class? If so, does this ancestor class have callback functions like afterRender()?

Many thanks!

Comment: Forgot to mention that I am using cakephp 1.3.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure such a callback exists specific for 'elements', but looking at the [source code](http://api.cakephp.org/1.3/source-class-View.html#322-408), `View::element()` renders an element using the *same* [`_render()`](http://api.cakephp.org/1.3/source-class-View.html#699-766) method as the View itself, and should trigger `beforeRender()` and `afterRender()`

### Creating a custom View Class and Custom Callbacks

You may use a custom 'View' class and override the `element()` method, for example to have your own 'custom' callbacks being triggered in helpers

Something like this;

app/view/app_view.php

```
class AppViewView extends View {
    /**
     * custom 'element()' method, triggers custom
     * before/aferRenderElement callbacks on all loaded helpers
     */
    public function element($name, $params = array(), $loadHelpers = false)
    {
        $this->_triggerHelpers('beforeRenderElement');
        $output = parent::element($name, $params, $loadHelpers);
        $this->_triggerHelpers('afterRenderElement');
    }

    /**
     * Names of custom callbacks
     */
    protected $_customCallBacks = array(
        'beforeRenderElement',
        'afterRenderElement',
    );

    function _triggerHelpers($callback)
    {
         if (!in_array($callback, $this->_customCallbacks)) {
             // it's a standard callback, let the parent class handle it
             return parent::_triggerHelpers($callback);
         }

         if (empty($this->loaded)) {
             return false;
         }
         $helpers = array_keys($this->loaded);
         foreach ($helpers as $helperName) {
             $helper =& $this->loaded[$helperName];
             if (is_object($helper)) {
                 if (
                      is_subclass_of($helper, 'Helper') 
                      && method_exists($helper, $callback)
                 ) {
                     $helper->{$callback}();
                 }
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Then, in your AppController specify the 'view' class to use;

```
class AppController extends Controller {
    public $view = 'AppView';
}
```

Comment: For Cake 2.x changes:  public $view = 'AppView' -> public $viewClass = 'App'; (OR 'plugin_name.App' and: $output -> return $output